# Facebook denies access of my app

Tags: facebook, cross-domain, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app that shows the share popup.
I have encountered a problem when trying to get it working form a different server.
I get the following error:

> Error An error occurred with myapp. Please try again later.
>
> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application
>   Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

How can I enable it to work from all servers? no matter if they are mine or not?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

*Note:
I would like it to be via the JS SDK.*

Comment: We can't use js sdk in this case. You will have to use server side apps as documented by Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook apps can only work with one main domain.
The main domain is derived from either the "Site url" or the "Mobile web url" as defined in the app settings page in the Developers application.

You can however add subdomains for that same domain.
For example, let's say your "Site url" is `http://app.example.com`, you can add more subdomains which you want to use with facebook by adding them to the "App Domains" field in the settings page (basic tab).
You can add subdomains like: `http://sub1.example.com` or `http://example.com`.

If you try to add a url that does not derive from that you should get the following error message when trying to save the settings:

> **Error**
>   DOMAIN_YOU_ADDED must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Web
>   URL.

---

## Edit

You have a problem if you want to use the `FB.ui` method.
The fb sdk will only accept usage from your own domain, and if you load an iframe from your own domain then the parent window (which is of another domain) won't be able to communicate with that iframe (same origin policy).

What you should be able to do is use the direct url of the [feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/):

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

You can open that in a new window/tab, or if it's an action of a user click then even open a pop-up.
But you won't be able to use the iframe dialog of the sdk.

Comment: Could I create an iframe and make the request from my server? (but the iframe will origin from any domain/server)? will that work?

Comment: Can you maybe explain a bit more about your situation and what you're trying to accomplish? Is this a canvas app? Why are you trying to use other domains? etc...

Comment: This is not a canvas app, I want my app to work from several "unknown" servers as a share tool that will work with the Facebook share popup.
The website adds a js script from my servers and should have the option to share right away.

Comment: Can you please add the code you are currently using to your original question? The code that results in the error you posted.

Comment: Its a normal js sdk request. (using the UI)

Comment: Isn't the feed dialog deprecated?

Comment: Why would you think that it has been deprecated? Go to the official page about it (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) it says nothing about deprecation.